# How to set the seasonality length to 7 using the ets function in R?

Tags: r, forecasting, seasonality

I am new to R and am hoping to use `ets` from the `forecast` package to forecast daily data which has a weekly pattern.

Is there any way of setting the length of seasonality to 7?

Answer (score 2):

The seasonality is set in your data:

```
x <- ts(rnorm(100),frequency=7)
ets(x)
```

This way you tell that your data is seasonal, and function implementing particular method either uses this information or ignores it. That is how `auto.arima` works, so it should be the same for `ets`, since they both are from the same package **forecast**.